# Flutter boolean variable not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have issue with the below code written in Flutter. I am trying to implement a search bar where I will show the results based on the match query string. The variable isStorage is set to false in the beginning. However, when I try to update its value inside _getALlPosts(), it is not getting updated.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 final SearchBarController<Post> _searchBarController = SearchBarController();
 bool isReplay = false;
 bool isStorage = false;

 Future<List<Post>> _getALlPosts(String text) async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: text.length == 4 ? 2 : 1));

List<Post> posts = [];
var random = new Random();

if (text.contains("pha")) {
  isStorage = true;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setState` to update the value:

```
if (text.contains("pha")) {
     setState(() {
      isStorage = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing a setState wrapping the `isStorage = true;`

```
setState(() {
  isStorage = true;
});
```